# Python ANOVA or MANOVA

Tags: correlation, anova, python, manova, pandas

I have a datasets with samples from various locations. At each of these locations I measured the concentrations of various genes. I saved the results in pandas dataframe and would like to compare the gene profiles of the different locations now to see if they are different and how much different they are from each other.

I wanted to use a MANOVA in Python to do this but I can't figure out how to get this done in Python.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
    sample  gene    ARG/16S
0   Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
1   Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
2   Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
3   Diepoldsau  Sul1    3.899208e-05
4   Diepoldsau  Sul1    7.973564e-05
5   Diepoldsau  Sul1    2.578990e-05
6   Diepoldsau  IC      1.231495e-03
7   Diepoldsau  IC      1.348069e-03
8   Diepoldsau  IC      8.651188e-04
9   Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
10  Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
11  Diepoldsau  qnrS    0.000000e+00
... ... ... ...
831 Utrecht blaSHV  0.000000e+00
832 Utrecht blaSHV  0.000000e+00
833 Utrecht TetB    0.000000e+00
834 Utrecht TetB    0.000000e+00
835 Utrecht Int1    0.000000e+00
836 Utrecht Int1    0.000000e+00
837 Utrecht qnrS    0.000000e+00
838 Utrecht qnrS    0.000000e+00
839 Utrecht Sul1    0.000000e+00
840 Utrecht Sul1    0.000000e+00
841 Utrecht IC      0.000000e+00
842 Utrecht IC      0.000000e+00
843 Utrecht TetM    0.000000e+00
844 Utrecht TetM    0.000000e+00
845 Utrecht VanA    0.000000e+00
846 Utrecht VanA    0.000000e+00
847 Utrecht VanB    0.000000e+00
848 Utrecht VanB    0.000000e+00
849 Utrecht TetM    2.442420e-05
850 Utrecht TetM    2.679794e-05
851 Utrecht VanA    0.000000e+00
```

Is MANOVA the right way to compare them? And if so: how to do this in Python?

Comment: Do you want to analyze how `ARG/16S` varies depending on `sample` and `gene`?

Comment: I analyzed them depending on sample and gene by grouping them and calculating the mean and std. What I would like to do now is comparing the profiles of these means according to the location (sample). SO: if location 1/sample 1 has certain concentrations of gene 1, gene 2 and gene 3, how does the combination of these values compare to the concentrations of the other locations and are there significant differences between these concentration profiles between different locations